# How to replace fragments in ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I have a ViewPager2 with TabLayout in my android java application and it has 2 fragments AudioFoldersFragment and VideoFoldersFragment. Both fragments have a recycler view and have some items(folder names) in the recycler view. Transition between both Audio and Video folders fragments is done via ViewPager2 with TabLayout.

On click of the items(folder names) I want to replace that fragment(Let's say I clicked on an item from fragment AudioFoldersFragment) of ViewPager2 to a new fragment AudioFilesList(Which has list of audio files inside that folder).

How can I achieve this replacement of fragments?

I tried using FragmentManager but it won't work because Transaction require FragmentContainerView which I'm not using because I'm using ViewPager2 with TabLayout, which gives error of **ViewPager2 does not support direct child views**

Is there any efficient way to replace the fragments?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few ways to replace fragments in a ViewPager2:

1. Use ViewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false) before replacing, and setUserInputEnabled(true) after. This prevents the user from swiping while you're changing fragments.

   ```
    viewPager.setUserInputEnabled(false);
   ```

   // Replace fragment

   viewPager.setUserInputEnabled(true);
2. Use ViewPager2.setCurrentItem() to change the displayed fragment.

   viewPager.setCurrentItem(newFragmentIndex, false);
3. Use FragmentStateAdapter and update the dataset/list of fragments.

   adapter.setFragments(updatedFragmentList);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
4. Use FragmentTransaction to replace the fragment within the ViewPager2 like:

   FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   transaction.replace(viewPager.getId(), newFragment);
   transaction.commit();

using ViewPager2 adapter methods, setCurrentItem or setUserInputEnabled are best. Avoid FragmentTransaction unless you handle the backstack correctly.

Comment: I want to change the current fragment to another 3rd fragment.
Using FragmentTransaction won't work because it gives error of ViewPager2 does not support direct child views.